# how to set privatetmp=false permanently in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1045-aws x86_64) on AWS.   I am running PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7 (cli) (built: Oct  7 2020 15:24:25) ( NTS )

When I migrated to 18.04 from 16  I had to set up the following:

sudo su

nano /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service

[Service]
...
PrivateTmp=true  <-- Changed this to "false"

Then do the following:

/var/tmp$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload

/var/tmp$ sudo service apache2 restart

All ran fine after this but as of a few days ago the setting PrivateTmp=false changed to PrivateTmp=true   so no files got written into the folder /var/tmp that my application depends on.    My suspicion is that an update happened and it changed the setting of PrivateTmp=false.   I am not sure how to proved that.

My questions:

is there a way to make the setting sticky and not have it undone by the update process.

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the apache unit file to:

```
/etc/systemd/system
```

Unit files in this directory supersede the default location and will not be replaced when the package receives an update. Modify the unit file as needed, then issue:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh.  You want me to copy this file:  /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service   to  /etc/systemd/system

Comment: I did not hear back.   I did the following:    sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service /etc/systemd/system/   and I will assume that this will take care of the issue.  Thank you  for the help.  This issue can be considered closed.

Answer (score 11):

Use the command `sudo systemctl edit apache2`, this will create an `override.conf` file in `/etc/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/` which will not be... overridden on a system update :-) and add these lines:

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=false
```

You can also create that file with any name (but ending in `.conf`) using your preferred editor.

Remebember to run `systemctl daemon-reload` command after that.